# Error on voting on questions

Tags: support

For the past couple weeks or so, whenever I vote on a question, I get a yellow box saying that an error has occurred and I should try again later. However, the vote is registered despite the error. This doesn't happen on voting on answers. Also, apparently it only happens under Chrome (Win7) - not on Firefox. Anyone else experiences this? Is this a known problem?

Comment: Are you saying *every* vote actually does this? I've seen this a couple times, but not enough to establish any patterns, and it was also more than a couple weeks ago.  If it happens every time, you could probably use the developer tools to debug it.

Comment: @Renesis, it seemed to me like it's every vote, but now I'm not so sure. Also, it stopped for now :)

Answer (score 1):

Haven't seen any other reports of this. Have you tried clearing your browser cache?

There are some fairly serious new caching bugs in Chrome 11 and onward.

Comment: Actually, looks like it stopped... I don't know, maybe it only seemed like it appears every single time. It did appear a lot in any case. I'll keep track of it from now on and hope to come up with more systematic observations.